# How to display both location and time on a world time app built with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, world-map

```
**main.dart**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:world_time/pages/choose_location.dart';
import 'package:world_time/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:world_time/pages/loading.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Loading(),
        '/home': (context) => Home(),
        '/location': (context) => ChooseLocation(),
      },
    ));

**home.dart**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Map data = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    data = data.isNotEmpty ? data : ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    print(data);

    // set background
    String bgImage = data['isDaytime'] ? 'day.png' : 'night.png';
    Color bgColor = data['isDaytime'] ? Colors.blue : Colors.indigo[700];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/$bgImage'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 120.0, 0, 0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    dynamic result =
                        await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
                    setState(() {
                      data = {
                        'time': result['time'],
                        'result': result['location'],
                        'isDaytime': result['isDaytime'],
                        'flag': result['flag'],
                      };
                    });
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.edit_location,
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                  ),
                  label: Text(
                    'Edit Location',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      data['location'] ?? '',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 38.0,
                        letterSpacing: 2.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Text(
                  data['time'] ?? '',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 66.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


**choose_location.dart**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:world_time/services/world_time.dart';

class ChooseLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChooseLocationState createState() => _ChooseLocationState();
}

class _ChooseLocationState extends State<ChooseLocation> {
  List<WorldTime> locations = [
    WorldTime(url: 'Europe/London', location: 'London', flag: 'uk.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Europe/Berlin', location: 'Athens', flag: 'greece.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Cairo', location: 'Cairo', flag: 'egypt.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Africa/Nairobi', location: 'Nairobi', flag: 'kenya.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'America/Chicago', location: 'Chicago', flag: 'usa.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'America/New_York', location: 'New York', flag: 'usa.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Asia/Seoul', location: 'Seoul', flag: 'south_korea.png'),
    WorldTime(url: 'Asia/Jakarta', location: 'Jakarta', flag: 'indonesia.png'),
  ];

  void updateTime(index) async {
    WorldTime instance = locations[index];
    await instance.getTime();
    // navigate to home screen
    Navigator.pop(context, {
      'location': instance.location,
      'flag': instance.flag,
      'time': instance.time,
      'isDaytime': instance.isDaytime,
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build function ran');
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
        title: Text('Choose a Location'),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: locations.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  updateTime(index);
                },
                title: Text(locations[index].location),
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      AssetImage('assets/${locations[index].flag}'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


**loading.dart**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:world_time/services/world_time.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
  void setupWorldTime() async {
    WorldTime instance = WorldTime(
        location: 'Berlin', flag: 'germany.png', url: 'Europe/Berlin');
    await instance.getTime();
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
      'location': instance.location,
      'flag': instance.flag,
      'time': instance.time,
      'isDaytime': instance.isDaytime,
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupWorldTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitFadingCircle(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


**world_time.dart**

import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class WorldTime {
  String location; // location name for the UI
  String time; //the time in that location
  String flag; //url to an asset flag icon
  String url; //location url for api endpoint
  bool isDaytime; //true or false if daytime or not

  WorldTime({this.location, this.flag, this.url});

  Future<void> getTime() async {
    //make the request
    Response response =
        await get(Uri.parse('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url'));
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    //print(data);

    //get properties from data

    String datetime = data['datetime'];
    String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1, 3);
    //print(datetime);
    //print(offset);

    //create DateTime object
    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));

    //set the time property
    isDaytime = now.hour > 6 && now.hour < 20 ? true : false;
    time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
  }
}

WorldTime instance =
    WorldTime(location: 'Berlin', flag: 'germany.png', url: 'Europe/Berlin');
```

Here are my codes for building a World time app on flutter

No error message seen on the output, but when a new city or location is selected, It displays only the time on the device without displaying the corresponding city for the current time displayed on the screen. Please how can I fix this without blowing up my codes. Thanks

Comment: Hi! Try to minimize your question. It has too much code without focus on the problem. It is also better to use common Flutter terms like `Text` and `Column` instead `time` and `city on the screen`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your flatbutton onpressed you have set the location key to 'result' change it to 'location'.

```
FlatButton.icon(
              onPressed: () async {
                dynamic result =
                    await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
                setState(() {
                  data = {
                    'time': result['time'],
                      // Change This
                  >>>  'result': result['location'], <<<
                      // To This
                  >>>  'location': result['location'], <<<
                    'isDaytime': result['isDaytime'],
                    'flag': result['flag'],
                  };
                });
              },
```